# Good tools for writing rest api technical especification

Tags: web-services, api, rest, documentation, specifications

What are good tools for writing rest api technical especification and documentation? I need to specify urls, routes, endpoints.

Another approach would be to automatically generate an API documentation reverse engineering its code. It's a C# webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three main languages to do that. You can then generate documentations from this using additional tools around these languages.

- [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) is a very popular and active language for Web API based on the JSON format.
- [RAML](http://raml.org/) is based on the YAML format.
- [API Blueprint](https://apiblueprint.org/) is based on Markdown. This makes it very easy to read.

Another tool called [Slate](https://github.com/tripit/slate) is documentation-oriented. It allows to generate beautiful documentation with sample calls in different programming languages.

You can notice that the tool [Restlet Studio](http://studio.restlet.com/#/) allows you to define the structure of your RESTful service online and get then corresponding Swagger or RAML structure. You can even generate documentations (or client kits, server skeletons) based on these formats.

Hope it answers your question!
Thierry